# Allocate storage for array of structs in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct, constructor

I am trying to dynamically allocate storage for an array of structures, in the constructor.  I am new to C++, and have tried all sorts of syntax variations, but now I am wondering whether this can be done at all.

```
struct Trade
{
    int index;
}

define MAX_TRADES 5000
struct foo
{
    Trade *trade [MAX_TRADES];

    int cumeTradeCount;

    foo() :
        cumeTradeCount(0),
    {
        // here is where I want to allocate storage for cumeTradeCount Trade structures
        ....

        memset(trade, 0, cumeTradeCount   * sizeof(Trade*));
    }
}
```

Specifically, what I am trying to figure out is how I can allocate storage for 'cumeTradeCount' structures, in the constructor.
If I were doing this in C, I would do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cumeTradeCount; ++i)
    trade[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(Trade *));
```

Comment: `memset` does allocate memory - it sets to a particular value. Since you're  initializing `cumeTradeCount=0`, the `memset` also won't actually do anything. Plus, the trailing comma will make this code not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to read a good C++ book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Your code allocates 5000 pointers on the stack.

To allocate 5000 `Trade` objects on stack, just use `Trade trade[MAX_TRADES]`... Example:

```
struct Trade
{
    int index;
};

#define MAX_TRADES 5000
struct foo
{
    Trade trade[MAX_TRADES];

    int cumeTradeCount;

    foo() : 
        cumeTradeCount(0)
    {
        // allocate storage for cumeTradeCount Trade structures
        //memset(trade, 0, cumeTradeCount   * sizeof(Trade*));
        // You don't need it
    }
};
```

As for heap, You use the operator `new` to allocate on the heap.

Change this: `Trade *trade [MAX_TRADES];` to `Trade *trade = new Trade[MAX_TRADES];`

Since its a class member, below is how it's done. But don't forget to `delete` it in your destructor... A full example below...

```
struct Trade
{
    int index;
};

#define MAX_TRADES 5000
struct foo
{
    Trade *trade;

    int cumeTradeCount;

    foo() : trade(new Trade[MAX_TRADES]),
        cumeTradeCount(0)
    {
        // allocate storage for cumeTradeCount Trade structures
        //memset(trade, 0, cumeTradeCount   * sizeof(Trade*));
        // You don't need it
    }

    ~foo() { delete[] trade; }
};
```

. I strongly advice you to use an `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. And again, in C++, we prefer to use `const` and `constexpr` to `#defines` --> still, [You need to read a good C++ book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Below, will save you many unforeseen headaches.

```
#include <vector>
struct Trade
{
    int index;
};

#define MAX_TRADES 5000
struct foo
{
    std::vector<Trade> trade;
    int cumeTradeCount;

    foo() : trade(MAX_TRADES),
        cumeTradeCount(0)
    { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trade* trade [MAX_TRADES];
```

is not a dynamic allocation. It is a fixed size array of 5000 **pointers to** `Trade`.

If this is what you want, you can just set them all to `NULL` or better `nullptr` and then fill the ones you need like this:

```
trade[i] = new Trade();
```

Don't forget to use `delete` in your destructor and implement a proper assignment, copy-constructors and copy-assignments.

If you want a dynamic array, use something like this:

```
Trade* trade[];
//in constructor
trade = new Trade*[sizeOfArray]; //remember those pointers are still uninitialized
```

or if you dont need pointers:

```
Trade trade[];
//in constructor
trade = new Trade[sizeOfArray];
```

Since you are asking about C++, it would be way easier to use

- `std::array<Trade*,NUM_TRADES>` (for fixed number of pointers),
- `std::array<Trade,NUM_TRADES>` (for fixed number of `Trade`s),
- `std::vector<Trade*>` (for variable number of pointers),
- `std::vector<Trade>` (for variable number of `Trade`s),